# Strange table behavior

Tags: html, html-table

There seems to be a strange effect that I've observed with tables.  See the two fiddles below.

http://jsfiddle.net/v5co5uy7/  (why are the cells in the left column pushed down?)

http://jsfiddle.net/v5co5uy7/1/  (the cells in the left column are positioned properly)

The only difference here is the final

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;" align="center"><br><br><br><br><br><br></td>
```

My question: Why do I need all of those `<br>`'s in order to move the "(k + __)(k + __)" part up into the proper place?

Comment: You should include relevant code for reproducing the issue *in the question itself*. Fiddles are just an extra convenience.

Comment: You also need to defined what “positioned properly” means.

Comment: "positioned properly" is where the "(k + __)(k + __)" is in the second fiddle.

Comment: That’s not a proper definition, and you should clarify the question by editing it, not in comments.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela:  So, you have 3 criticisms of how I've asked this question and 0 answers or ideas.... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is only reproducible on chrome.

HTML cell takes up the space it needs to display the content. If the height is undefined, the cells span according to content.
If you wish to set the last `tr` so as to cover remaining height, set its height to `100%`, instead of adding `<br>` to it.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/v5co5uy7/3/

Comment: I'm using FF and 1.) the problem is still here.  2.) Your solution isn't working... at least in FF.

Comment: I agree, I checked in FF the problem is still there. It seems cell size is done differently by different browsers.


I'm not sure why you are using multiple rows in left column; If it is just to create padding between first and third row, you can just create 2 columns and use `<br>` between internal tables.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a workaround.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/v5co5uy7/4/

```
<tr height="20px">
```

Was needed on a couple rows.